# Keep items at bottom of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4, i'm trying to keep a row with some columns at the bottom of the page. When adding position fixed and bottom, it's throwing off the placement and not staying centered. I assume this has something to do with flex?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1dLrfsbh/1/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="mt-3 text-center justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" class="img-fluid logo" />

    <div class="chk-actions">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" />
              </a>
           </div>

           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <a href="#">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" />
               </a>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

```
.chk-actions {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.chk-actions a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What's your grid gutter? 30px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the flex. It's about defining the position of the element. So far you have only defined its bottom value/position.

If I assume you are using Bootstrap's default grid gutter of 30px, I'd simply add 15px for the left and right.

```css
.chk-actions {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}

.chk-actions a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="mt-3 text-center justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" class="img-fluid logo" />

    <div class="chk-actions">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" />
              </a>
           </div>

           <div class="col-lg-6">
               <a href="#">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" />
               </a>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```